# Return JSON Response from a MySQL Query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I have a jQuery AJAX function like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'crud/clients.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 
        id:rowID,
        clientID:$('#clientID').val(),
        clientName:$('#clientName').val()
    }
    success: function(data){ 
        alert(data); 
    }
});
```

I then setup my query in the `clients.php` file. Finally, I execute the query with this line:

```
mysql_query( $sql ) or die(mysql_error());
```

How do I return the results of that query in JSON format so that my AJAX function can catch whatever is returned?

Comment: As a side note, you should move away from the mysql_* functions in favor of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: What's a "prepared statement"? Sorry, I'm new :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this :

```
$q = mysql_query( $sql ) or die(mysql_error());
$res = json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($q));
echo $res;
```

you can also take a look at : [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) & [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Comment: Ok, I put these lines in my code and intentionally messed up the `$sql` query with a field name that doesn't exist in the table. When I do this, and step through the PHP, it just stops at the `mysql_query( $sql ) or die(mysql_error());` line and doesn't proceed down to the `json_encode` line. Now, when there is no error, and the DB updates correctly, I can see that `null` is returned. Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: @FastTrack try `echo $q;` instead of `echo $res;` if update is ok you will get `1` else you will get `0`

Comment: Ok, I'll try in a bit and post back with my results.